# Hosting providers for Matlab based Dot net application

Tags: asp.net, matlab, web-hosting, matlab-compiler

I have developed a Dot Net based web application that uses matlab code compiled into dlls and deployed it on local server with 'Matlab' instsalled. It works on local server well. However, I want to deploy it on a hosting domain for ease of access. But I dont know about any hosting providers that support working of matlab dlls with web application. Is there any suggestion about such hosting providers and how should I deploy it on a hosting domain.
PS: on my remote server i had to install Matlab to run that application when deployed on IIS server ie with just mcr instlled the application was not working.

I'm doing it for the first time so I dont know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

On [this paper](https://es.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/tag-team/Objects/d/Deep_Learning_in_Cloud_Whitepaper.pdf) explains how to put matlab on Amazon EC2

Amazon [had AMI instances](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122118-what-cloud-services-does-mathworks-support)

MATLAB AMI on EC2

```
The pre-built AMI offerings on Amazon have been depreciated and will no longer be available. You are able to work with Amazon or another cloud service provider to get you own machine instance and use your license there.

To best run MATLAB on a cloud instance, you will need your license configured as a Login Named User (LNU). If you have an Individual or Group license activated as a Standalone Named User , you can configure it as an LNU at [https://www.mathworks.com/licensecenter/lnu.][3]
```

Also on [windows azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/matlab-mdcs-cluster)

You can get any host provider with IAAS and apply matlba LNU license

Comment: Thanks for the response I will try this out and post the updates.